# Ruby: pass options parameter between methods

Tags: ruby, methods

If `public_method` gets called:

```
public_method hello: 'world'

def public_method options = {}
    puts options[:hello]
    private_method options: options
end

private

def private_method options = {}
    puts options[:hello]
end
```

It puts `'world` and the forwards to `private_method`.
That method does not receive `{:options=>{:hello=>'world'}}` like expected. Instead it receives `{:options=>{:options=>{:hello=>'world'}}}`.

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: "how can I change this behaviour?" - don't do the wrapping then. `private_method options`

Comment: Try `private_method options`

Comment: `private_method options: options` means `private_method({options: options})`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I originally only did this because passing just options gave me an error. But it's working now, seems like there was something wrong with the options hash then when I first tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `public_method`, `options` is already a Hash. When you call `private_method` you embed it in another Hash. Don't do it.

```
def public_method options = {}
    puts options[:hello]
    private_method options
end
```